# Using "false" in if statement KSH

Tags: if-statement, ksh

My code:

```
if $bVar1 && $bVar2
then
    echo "bVar1 & bVar2 are true"
elif $bVar3 && !$bVar4
then
    echo "bVar3 is true; bVar4 is false"
fi
```

The `!$bVar4` part does not work as expected. I've tried:

```
elif $bVar3 && !$bVar4
elif $bVar3 && !${bVar4}
elif $bVar3 && !$(bVar4)
```

but I cannot get this line to return `true` when `bVar3=true` and `bVar4=false`.

For completeness, variables are assigned like this:

```
bVar3=true
bVar4=false
```

(Of course, I can add a nested `if` statement within the `elif` like this:

```
if $bVar1 && $bVar2
then
    echo "bVar1 & bVar2 are true"
elif $bVar3
then
    if $bVar4
    then
        : #pass
    else
        echo "bVar3 is true; bVar4 is false"
    fi
fi
```

but that is unnecessary, isn't it? BTW - I did try this and this code works.)

Comment: Whitespace is your friend.  Did you try `! $bVar4`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell - it was that simple! Post that as an answer and I will accept (record time, btw, 5 minutes...!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shells are finicky with respect to whitespace.  For example, in an interactive bash shell with certain settings, `!$bVar4` will attempt to do history expansion as a result of the `!`, but `! $bvar4` will expand the string `$bvar4`, attempt to execute the resulting string, and then negate the return value.  Adding a space after the `!` is probably necessary to ensure the expected semantics.